# Распределить посты по условию (по дате) в два Div'a

Tags: php, joomla

Необходимо поместить посты которые соответствуют условию (по дате) в один div, а те что нет —  в другой. 
Есть код, который отвечает за вывод постов:

```
<div id="itemListPrimary">
        <?php foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item): ?>


        <div class="itemContainer-list">
                <?php
                // Load category_item.php by default
                    $this->item = $item;
                    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                ?>

        </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
```

К постам я добавил дополнительные поля в которых указывается дата, скажем дата завершения акции:

```
<?php if  ($this->item->extraFields->finish->value) : ?>                    
    <?php
    $date_offer_finish = $this->item->extraFields->finish->value; // дата завершения акции

    $date_now = JHTML::_('date', 'now', JText::_('d F Y')); // текущая дата
    ; ?>                                
<?php endif; ?>
```

На основании этого я попытался сделать условие, подружить эти два куска кода и распределить посты в два дива:

1) посты в которых установлена сегодняшняя дата или более поздняя; (акутальные)

2) посты в которых установлена дата ранее, чем сегодня. (истекшие)

т.е вот так:

```
<div class="itemContainer-list">    
   <div id="actual">
            ...
   </div>
   <div id="ending">
            ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Но к сожалению ничего не вышло. Прошу помочь с решением вопроса, интересны любые варианты. Спасибо!

---

---

Правка 1.
Воспользовался рекомендациями, которые дали в ответе и получился следующий код:

```
<?php if(isset($this->primary) && count($this->primary)): ?>
<!-- Primary items -->
<div id="actual">
    <div class="itemContainer-list">

        <?php foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item):
         if (!empty($this->item->extraFields->finish->value) || strtotime($this->item->extraFields->finish->value) > time()){
        continue;
        }
        $this->item = $item;
        echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
        endforeach; ?>

    </div>
```

```
<div id="ending">
    <div class="itemContainer-list">

        <?php foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item):
        if (strtotime($this->item->extraFields->finish->value) < time()){
        continue;
        }
        $this->item = $item;
        echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
        endforeach; ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Некоторые посты могут не содержать значение даты, т.е. срок действия неизвестен или бессрочный, поэтому в `<div id="actual">` я добавил еще одно условие `(!empty($this->item->extraFields->finish->value)`.

Но в результате распределение не происходит корректно! В `<div id="actual">` попадают первые два поста, в `<div id="ending">` только первый.

В общей сложности постов около 30. Среди них есть посты без дат, истекшие посты с датами и актуальные посты с датами.

Я упростил начальный код, и убрал часть в которой происходит разбитие на столбцы.

Исходный код:

```
<?php if(isset($this->primary) && count($this->primary)): ?>
    <!-- Primary items -->
    <div id="itemListPrimary">
        <?php foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item): ?>

        <?php
        // Define a CSS class for the last container on each row
        if( (($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_primary_columns'))==0) || count($this->primary)<$this->params->get('num_primary_columns') )
            $lastContainer= ' itemContainerLast';
        else
            $lastContainer='';
        ?>

        <div class="itemContainer-list">
            <?php
                // Load category_item.php by default
                $this->item = $item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php if(($key+1)%($this->params->get('num_primary_columns'))==0): ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Подскажите, что сделал не так?

Comment: а что мешает сделать два foreach? в первом выводить актуальные, во втором истёкшие

Comment: @Arsen  мешает незнание php :). именно это я пробовал... Если не сложно подскажите плз

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь в `$this->item->extraFields->finish->value` у вас микросекундами, если нет, всегда храните и cравнивайте даты только в в формате микросекунд - [time()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php) Если у вас дата в другом формате, нужно поменять формат даты, например через [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php)

```
 <div class="itemContainer-list">
        <div id="actual">
            <?php foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item):

                    if($this->item->extraFields->finish->value < time()){
                        continue;
                    }
                        $this->item = $item;
                        echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                    endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="ending">

            <?php foreach($this->primary as $key=>$item):

                    if($this->item->extraFields->finish->value > time()){
                        continue;
                    }
                        $this->item = $item;
                        echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                    endforeach; ?>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: к сожалению дата не в микросекундах. Вариант не сработал, по всякому! Дело в том, что значение даты генерирует CMS. Пробовал изменить формат даты strtotime(), чего-то внятного добиться не удалось. Я сделал две переменные '$date_offer_finish = $this->item->extraFields->finish->value;  $date_now = JHTML::_('date', 'now', JText::_('d F Y'));' затем ' $actual = $date_now - $date_offer_finish;  if ($actual < 1) $result='1'; if ($actual > 0) $result='2'; ' И проверил как работает: '  echo $result;  ' . Актуальные и истекшие соотв. 1 и 2. Но сделать фильтрацию используя такой метод не вышло!

Comment: пробовал Ваш способ по разному, не вышло. Может быть возможно реализовать распределение по div'ам используя логику что описал выше на базе ' $actual = $date_now - $date_offer_finish; ' или вроде того? Пытался адаптировать сам — не выходит!

Comment: @Ivan мой метод рабочий, проблема в том что вы логику не поняли. Зачем вы генерируете $date_now  по стандарту джумлы? я же там поставил time() - это тоже самое но в микросекундах. Вы прочитали то что я написал? видимо нет "всегда храните и cравнивайте даты только  в формате микросекунд"  а вы берёте и стравнивайте, например 10 Ноября 2018 !!! Вы можете сделать echo $this->item->extraFields->finish->value и написать тут какую дату показывает, какой формат?

Comment: совершенно верно, я сравниваю даты в формате 'd F Y', как Вы написали в примере 10 Ноября 2018. Это тот формат в котором выводится дата дополнительного поля.  Стока которая отвечает за вывод даты в доп. поле находится в "models/item" и выглядит она так "$value = JHTML::_('date', $value, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'), $offset);". Можно изменить непосредственно в файле, но тогда нужно будет править шаблоны вывода. Преобразовать value непосредственно  из шаблона у меня не вышло.

Comment: Поэтому я поступил проще — сделал сравнение с датой joomla в таком же формате '$date_now = JHTML::_('date', 'now', JText::_('d F Y'));' ' — работает.

Comment: добиться успеха путем преобразования из шаблона через  DateFormat, и strtotime() не увенчались успехом

Comment: >Поэтому я поступил проще — сделал сравнение с датой joomla. Вы не поступили проще... вы совершили ужастную ошибку, нельзя сравнивать две даты как текст!!! если strtotime() не смогли получить милисекунды, значит что то не так сделали, копайте в этом направлении, когда получите микросекунды, тогда вся логика сработает.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: мне удалось привести даты в один формат! проверил вывод установленных дат и текушей time() в unix и обратно — все верно и  соответствует действительности. Но при реализации Вашего способа возникли трудности, условия работают некорректно. Добавил правку в свой вопрос, не могли бы взглянуть где ошибка? Спасибо!

Comment: @Ivan если значение даты нет пост должен попасть под Завершённые?

Comment: нет он должен попасть в "актуальные", как бессрочный

Comment: тогда зачем || ?   может правильнее &&  т.е значение не пусто и (&&) значение больше текушей даты

Comment: так тоже делал, результат тот же самый

Comment: что то криво делаете )) заметил что у вас в прмере  определение переменной $this->item идёт в низу а сверху вы уже пробуете получить данные от $this->item. В joomla,  в category blog layout вся информация о контенте находится в переменной $items и по стандарту только до подключения шаблона категорий идёт присваевание данных к $this->item Вы там что то накосячили в default.php. По шагам проверьте все с начала.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Все получилось. Единственный момент в "истекшие" также попадали посты без даты! я методом тыка добавил условие "  !empty($this->item->extraFields->finish->value) == false ". В результате получилось " if (!empty($this->item->extraFields->finish->value) == false || strtotime($this->item->extraFields->finish->value) > time()){ " Скажите пожалуйста, это корректно ? Спасибо!